# Instantiating a java object inside a for loop vs outside

Tags: java

What is the difference between doing this?

```
Test test = new Test();
for(Person person:personLst) {
    test.setName(person.getName());
    test.setId(person.getId());
}
```

Over this -

```
 for(Person person:personLst) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setName(person.getName());
    test.setId(person.getId());
}
```

Will the data get overwritten in either of the two cases?

Comment: Yes, but you can't use the variable outside of the loop in the second approach.

Comment: If my answer is the best answer to your question please accept it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have the same result **regarding object data overwriting** but with the overhead of creating the test object as many times as people in personLst. The coming overhead comes with an advantage of having a variable holding the person object state in the loop. In contrast, in the first case, you just have access to the latest person object data.

In other words in the first case some space is reserved in memory for the object test (that is for fields name and id):

```
Case 1:
Address    Memory Space
[test]---> [name]
           [id] 

            ...

[test]---> [nameN]
           [idN]
```

But in the second case you are creating new objects all the time, in different places in your memory (while the previous creations die when the specific loop step ends - which means that memory is freed at some point):

```
Case 2:
Address    Memory Space
[test]---> [name]
           [id] 

            ...

[testN]--->[nameN]
           [idN]
```

[test]...[testN] represent an address to the memory region representing your Test object (simplified model).

Thanks for the input https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580864/mark-w

Comment: In which case? Please state that.

Comment: He wont have the same result. In the first case he will have a reference to a person in test (the last in the list) in the second, there will be no reference... only a Person object(s) waiting to be GC'ed, because it will go out of scope.

Comment: Well his question doesn't state what he intends to do with the test variable which of course won't be accessible outside of the loop. I made it more specific

Comment: You recent update is also not true. In the first example he updates the memory address for test repeatedly. In the second, he creates a new object at a new place in memory each iteration. These two are NOT the same.

Comment: I think he is talking about data overwriting (in the object) and not in memory. He is just learning Javascript I believe but could be wrong

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your diagram, but definitely +1 for NOT leaving a bad answer untouched.

Comment: I made the diagram a little more clear I believe. 
Variable test is an address or a pointer to the specific position of the object internals (name and id). Let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer, as we don't know

- If there are any side effects of setName / setId
- What you are going to do with the test object.

From what we can tell from your code, the second loop is just a no-op, and the first could be replaced with just updating with the last item in the list, and ignore the other entries.

Comment: If by no-op you mean, allocating memory for N instances of Person then making them eligable for GC immediately... Assuming an optimizer doesnt just remove all that...

Comment: @MarkW Yes, the optimizer would be fully entitled to re-use the object that goes out of scope at the end of the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

With the first :
test object attribute will have the attributes of the last person of the list

With the second :
you create any Test object as Person obejct that is only accessible inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Case1: you are creating only one instance of the class "Test" and changing its value in the loop. If any other method needs test as input this it is fine. You are converting Person object to Test object and passing it.

Case2: Here you are creating  multiple Test instance (equal to number of items in personLst). If you want to convert all the Person object to Test object and store in a list (or any collection) for future use then this is right.